# How to print faces on deck of cards in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to print a deck of 52 cards but have no clue how to print the faces. I have each printing the suit correctly. My current code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 52

char suits[4][9]= {"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};   
char faces[13][6]= {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9", "10","Jack",
                "Queen","King"};

int main()
{
    int i;
    char cards[SIZE];

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        printf("Card %2d = %s %s\n", i, faces[i%13], suits[i/13]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I placed a "?" where I'm not sure about. I'm not sure whats exactly going on. I'm guessing for suits it will take values i and divide by 13 to determine which 4 array choices it would choose but I don't know what to put in for the faces array.

Sorry if my question has problems. I'm still new to using stackoverflow. please forgive me

Comment: "Faces" is a bit vague in this question, but assuming you want to create an image of the front of each card, you'll probably want to start be obtaining a bitmap for each suit symbol. Unfortunately, further details about how to actually arrange them into an image depends very much on the platform and libraries you plan to use. You really should've fleshed out this question a little more.

Comment: OP just wants to print the arrays in order...

Comment: Where did you place the "?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ([check the example](http://ideone.com/UWKxgY))?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 52

char suits[4][9]= {"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};   
char faces[13][6]= {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9", "10","Jack",
                "Queen","King"};

int main()
{
    int i;
    char cards[SIZE];

    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        printf("Card %2d = %s %s\n", i, faces[i % 13], suits[i / 13]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

If this is what you were looking for, you just need to play around with the indexes.